# Time formatting and converting from string

Tags: time, go

I'm quite new to Go and mainly work in C#. I am currently working on something that will be used as a command to get the next bus. Currently it does not compile because I am struggling with understanding how to use the `time` package in Go.

I have an array of strings formatted as times when it is scheduled and another for the minutes when it is a regular service like so (there are many more times these are just an example:

```
var ScheduledTimes = []string{"06:34", "06:54", "17:09", "17:19"}
var RegularTimes = []string{"05", "50"}
```

So what I am currently doing is getting the current time and checking if it is in regular service by doing this:

```
func isWithinRegularService(check time.Time) bool {
    RegularStart, err := time.Parse(time.Kitchen, "10:05")
    RegularEnd, err := time.Parse(time.Kitchen, "13:52")
    return check.After(RegularStart) && check.Before(RegularEnd)
}

time := time.Now().UTC().Format("15:04")
if isWithinRegularService(time) { }
```

If it is in regular service, I will then determine what hour needs looking at (i.e this one or is the next service within the next hour)

```
if time.Minutes < 5 && time.Minutes >= 0 {
    RegularTimes[0] = fmt.Sprintf("%s%s", time.Hour+1, RegularTimes[0])
    RegularTimes[1] = fmt.Sprintf("%s%s", time.Hour+1, RegularTimes[1])
    RegularTimes[2] = fmt.Sprintf("%s%s", time.Hour+1, RegularTimes[2])
    RegularTimes[3] = fmt.Sprintf("%s%s", time.Hour+1, RegularTimes[3])
} else {
    RegularTimes[0] = fmt.Sprintf("%s%s", time.Hour, RegularTimes[0])
    RegularTimes[1] = fmt.Sprintf("%s%s", time.Hour, RegularTimes[1])
    RegularTimes[2] = fmt.Sprintf("%s%s", time.Hour, RegularTimes[2])
    RegularTimes[3] = fmt.Sprintf("%s%s", time.Hour, RegularTimes[3])
}
```

Before I pass that array to another func to give me the times to check between

```
type BusTime struct {
betweenStart string
betweenEnd   string
}

func getBusTime(busTimes []array, iteration int) BusTime {

    var timesToReturn BusTime

    if iteration == busTimes.Count()-1 {
        timesToReturn.betweenStart = busTimes[iteration]
        timesToReturn.betweenEnd = busTimes[0]
    } else {
        timesToReturn.betweenStart = busTimes[iteration]
        timesToReturn.betweenEnd = busTimes[iteration+1]
    }

    return timesToReturn
}

busTimes := getBusTime(quaylinkRegularTimes, i)
```

And lastly I then check if the time provided is between the times to compare:

```
check.After(start) && check.Before(end)
```

That is about it for this project. If it is not with regular service it will do the exact same but skip out determining what hour to look at.

Currently this does not build because I am using strings where I should be using times, I was hoping to get some guidance, some examples, and corrections on how to use times correctly to achieve what I'm looking to do. So far I believe my logic to the way this will flow is correct, but I'm stuck getting it to compile.

Comment: What problem do you have when you try to use Times? Please show a minimal example of the problem you have.

Comment: Hi, the problem I'm having is that I don't understand how to go about converting from string to a time, I've read a few places and when they parse the string to a time they all include the date, where mine just includes the time.

Comment: Using hours and minutes alone without a date is ambiguous. Is 23:59 before or after 00:01? If you only want to work with hours and minutes, I would just work with them as integers.

Comment: I think my logic would handle 23:59 and 00:01, However unable to check that it would yet. How would you go about doing it with integers?

Comment: A Time is a nanosecond instant in a specific location. What you are essentially asking for is the duration since 00:00. You could use Time.Duration, or make your own type with methods to work directly with the formats you want, using only a single integer of minutes or seconds since 00:00.

Comment: Much of your example code would fail to build. Could you update your post to include the compiler error you are receiving and a snippet of the offending function?

Comment: All of it is offending code, Because its mainly pseudo code and dummy code - trying to give a better impression of what I am aiming to achieve. It does not build at all - last paragraph.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since `time.Time` is a particular instant, at a particular location, using it for arbitrary clock time without a day or timezone can be awkward. What you're really looking for is the duration since 00:00, so a `time.Duration` makes more sense. You could even use your own type based on minutes since midnight for example, but if you use a `time.Duration` you'll be able to compose your times with `time.Time` more easily.

Here's an example function to parse your clock times, and minutes into a `time.Duration`

```
func ParseTime(t string) (time.Duration, error) {
    var mins, hours int
    var err error

    parts := strings.SplitN(t, ":", 2)

    switch len(parts) {
    case 1:
        mins, err = strconv.Atoi(parts[0])
        if err != nil {
            return 0, err
        }
    case 2:
        hours, err = strconv.Atoi(parts[0])
        if err != nil {
            return 0, err
        }

        mins, err = strconv.Atoi(parts[1])
        if err != nil {
            return 0, err
        }
    default:
        return 0, fmt.Errorf("invalid time: %s", t)
    }

    if mins > 59 || mins < 0 || hours > 23 || hours < 0 {
        return 0, fmt.Errorf("invalid time: %s", t)
    }

    return time.Duration(hours)*time.Hour + time.Duration(mins)*time.Minute, nil
}
```

You can also combine this with your own type, using the same underlying int64 type, so that you can easily format the time.Duration and add your own methods. It's up to you if returning a `Time` or a `time.Duration` from ParseTime is more convenient. The two here are directly convertible.

```
type Time int64

func (t Time) Hours() int {
    return int(time.Duration(t) / time.Hour)
}

func (t Time) Minutes() int {
    return int((time.Duration(t) % time.Hour) / time.Minute)
}

func (t Time) String() string {
    return fmt.Sprintf("%02d:%02d", t.Hours(), t.Minutes())
}
```

You could combine these like so: http://play.golang.org/p/E679m2wlUO